# how convert string into 2d list flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to convert string into 2d array in Dart flutter

```
[[Service, 300, 1], [Service, 4200, 1]]
```

This is string I want to convert into a List so I can use the following with ListView in Flutter.

```dart
List<String> stringList = (jsonDecode(serviceWantList) as List<dynamic>).cast<String>();
```

I have tried this but I'm not getting the result I want.

I want to access list like this

```
[[Service, 300, 1], [Service, 4200, 1]]
```

I want to convert this in 2 list
so I access like `index[0][0]`, `index[0][1]` and so on.

Comment: Are you saying the string is `"[[Service, 300, 1], [Service, 4200, 1]]"` ?

Comment: yes this is a string i want to convert this into 2d list

Comment: from where you're getting the string? Is this from JSON response from an API?

Comment: from api Im getting my response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonDecode would not work because the string is not a valid JSON. Try doing the below:

```
  String input =
      '[[Service is the best, 300, 1], [Man is awesome, 4200, 1],[Service is the best, 300, 1], [Man is awesome, 4200, 1]]';

  input = input.replaceAllMapped(
      RegExp(r'([a-zA-Z ]+)(?=,)'), (match) => '"${match.group(0)}"');
  List<List<dynamic>> output = List.from(jsonDecode(input))
      .map((e) => List.from(e).cast<dynamic>())
      .toList();
  print(output[0][0].runtimeType);
  print(output[0][1].runtimeType);
  print(output[1][0].runtimeType);
  print(output[1][1].runtimeType);
```

The problem is that the string contains unquoted text, which is not allowed in JSON; hence we need to enclose all the non-numeric values in the string in double quotes (").

Comment: what if i want to convert this '[[Service, 300, 1], [Man, 4200, 1]]' or '[[Service, 300, 1], [Man, 4200, 1],[ball, 300, 1], [Man, 4200, 1]]' its all dynamic

Comment: I have updated the implementation. The above should work for your cases.

Comment: [[Service is the best, 300, 1], [Man is awesome, 4200, 1]]' or [[Service is the best, 300, 1], [Man is awesome, 4200, 1],[Service is the best, 300, 1], [Man is awesome, 4200, 1]]' i want first string as a sentence and others as integer hope you understand my problem thanks you in advanced

Comment: The problem here is that your string is an invalid json and also contains unquoted text and one would have to resolved to parsing or hacking around it.

Comment: I have updated with a better solution that should fit all the mentioned cases and also maintains the runtimeType of the data